# how to start and stop Runnable

Tags: android-activity

Can anybody help with my project below. I need to Stop my Runnable Thread using start and stop button. What code will i put in the stop button?

---

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements OnClickListener {

```
Context context;
Runnable runnable;
Handler handler;
Thread myThread;
Button btnstart, btnstop;
boolean Running1 = true;
Toast toaststat;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    context = this;

    btnstart = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    btnstop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    btnstart.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnstop.setOnClickListener(this);


}





public class RunTimer implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        while(Running1){

            try{
                Thread.sleep(3000);}
            catch(InterruptedException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


            handler.post(new Runnable(){
                @Override
                public void run(){






                }
            });
        }
    }
}







@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch(v.getId()){
    case R.id.button1: //START
        myThread= new Thread(new RunTimer());
        myThread.start();

        break;
    case R.id.button2: //STOP

        break;
}



}
```

Answer (score 2):

The first thing you need to do is stop the thread. There used to be a `stop` method, but that has since been deprecated for reasons mentioned [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/misc/threadPrimitiveDeprecation.html).

What you should do is interrupt the thread which asks it to stop. You can call the interrupt method when button2 is pressed to do this.

```
case R.id.button2: //STOP
    myThread.interrupt();
    break;
```

Thread.interrupt produces a `InterruptedException`, which you have already caught. You then need to manually interrupt it from within the thread.

```
try {
    Thread.sleep(3000);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
}
```

For more information please read the docs for Thread's [interrupt](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.html#interrupt%28%29) method.